# Don't display conditionalPanel when condition is wrong

Tags: r, shiny

I try to create some shinyapp. I need to update sidebarPanel depends on condition received in server.R. The current code is shown below.
**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

main_mat <- matrix(data = c(1, 11, 3, 13,
                            12, 4, 8, 2,
                            3, 5, 14, 6),
                   nrow = 3, ncol = 4, byrow = T)
colnames(main_mat) <- c("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4")
rownames(main_mat) <- c("A1", "A2", "A3")
ai <- c(140, 160, 100)
bj <- c(80, 40, 150, 130, NA)
res1 <- ai
res2 <- bj
m <- cbind(main_mat, ai)
m <- rbind(m, bj)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Header"),
  
  
  sidebarPanel(
    width = 6,
    tags$h4("Table"),
    matrixInput(
      "sample",
      value = m,
      rows = list(
        names = TRUE
      ),
      cols = list(
        names = TRUE
      ),
      copy = TRUE,
      paste = TRUE
    )
  ),
  sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(condition = "output.cond() == 'dontwork'", textOutput("text")),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "output.cond() == 'work'", tableOutput("obs"))
      
    )
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  main_func <- function(df) {return(t(df))} 
  observe({
    if (sum(as.numeric(input$sample[4,1:4]), na.rm = T) == sum(as.numeric(input$sample[1:3,5]), na.rm = T)) {
      output$cond <- reactive('work')
    } else {
      output$cond <- reactive('dontwork')
    }
  })
  output$obs <- renderTable({main_func(input$sample)})
  
  
  observe(if (sum(as.numeric(input$sample[4,1:4]), na.rm = T) == sum(as.numeric(input$sample[1:3,5]), na.rm = T)) {
    output$text <- renderText("cond1")
  } else {
    output$text <- renderText("cond2")
  })
}
```

I expect that when the condition is true then only `output$obs` is displayed, and when the condition is not true, the `output$obs` is not displayed and only the `output$text` is displayed. But in fact, when i change values input values, `output$text` changes, but `tableOutput("obs")` still displaying. How can I hide the `tableOutput("obs")` if the condition is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define `output$cond` in an observer. You can proceed as follows:

```
output$cond <- reactive({
  ifelse(
    sum(as.numeric(input$sample[4,1:4]), na.rm = TRUE) == sum(as.numeric(input$sample[1:3,5]), na.rm = TRUE),
    "work", "dontwork"
  )
})
outputOptions(output, "cond", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

And in the UI:

```
conditionalPanel(
  "output.cond === 'work'",
  ......
)
```

(no parentheses in the condition)